# Install ESX4 on Intel board S5500BC, using board's SW raid?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

HW System is Intel SR1630, based on Intel board S5500BC + Two 320 GB Sata drives.

Drives are installed, configured and initialized as Raid-0 (mirror), using Intel's server deployment sw.

When trying to install ESX4 (either b164009 or 4.1 Beta) on this machine, it does not recognize the raid, but recognize them as two different drives, letting me chooes between them.

Is there a special driver needed to be added to the install process ?
Is such configuration supported by ESX4?

Thanks,

Zeevik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S5500BC is in [the VMware HCG](http://www.vmware.com/resources/guides.html) but the SR1630 is not explicitly called out either by VMware themselves or on the community support website. It's quite possible that the RAID controller is not supported, that does happen. Adding drivers to ESXi is not supported, although there are some variants (e.g those from Dell and HP) that include additional supported drivers for those vendors.

Answer (score 0):

Which do you mean RAID 0 or mirroring (RAID 1)?

Either way this is a hybrid HW/SW RAID controller that isn't supported in any way by ESX as there are no supporting drivers available. That said it shouldn't be hard or expensive to pick up a supported hardware-only-mirroring controller.